# matlab - averaging for a given interval

Tags: matlab, time, resolution

I can calculate daily averages of a data set like so:

```
Jday = datenum('2010-11-01 00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM'):60/(60*24):...
    datenum('2011-02-31 23:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM');
Dat = rand(length(Jday),1);
DateV = datevec(Jday);
[~,~,b] = unique(DateV(:,1:3),'rows');
AvDat = abs(accumarray(b,Dat,[],@nanmean));     
AvJday = abs(accumarray(b,Jday,[],@nanmean));
```

However, I would like to take an average of a data set given a number for the output resolution. For example, if I wrote

```
outRes = 86400; % in seconds
```

I would like to average the values so that the output resolution is equal to 86400 seconds, and if the `outRes` defined is shorter than the resolution of the data then no averaging will take place.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to detect the resolution of the data by:

```
CurrentRes=mean(diff(Jday))*86400;
if (~all(diff(Jday)==CurrentRes))
    error('Inequally distributed sampling times');
end

if (CurrentRes>outRes)
    return;
```

Then the amount you need to downsample by is:

```
AveragingFactor=outRes/CurrentRes;
```

Then you can average by discarding some samples at the end (or start) and averaging:

```
Dat = reshape(Dat(1:end-mod(length(Dat),AveragingFactor),:),AveragingFactor,[]);
AvDat = mean(Dat,1)'; % Transpose to keep it as a column vector if necessary.
```